# cant get the right values for previous minutes

Tags: javascript, datetime, web-applications, momentjs

```
<script>
        var train_arrivals = [
        '00:10',
        '00:15',
        '00:23',
        '00:35',
        '00:43',
        '00:58',
        '01:05',
        '01:13',
        '01:20',
        '01:37',
        '01:48',
        '02:15',
        '02:25',
        '02:40',
        '02:55',
        '03:00',
        '03:09',
        '03:21',
        '03:37',
        '03:52',
        '04:15',
        '04:30',
        '04:44',
        '04:58',
        '05:16',
        '05:31',
        '05:49',
        '06:00',
        '06:26',
        '06:56',
        '08:06',
        '07:24',
        '07:43',
        '07:58',
        '08:06',
        '08:13',
        '08:28',
        '08:43',
        '08:58',
        '09:05',
        '09:13',
        '09:28',
        '09:43',
        '09:58',
        '10:05',
        '10:38',
        '11:00',
        '11:38',
        '12:38',
        '13:38',
        '14:38',
        '15:38',
        '16:00',
        '16:39',
        '17:00',
        '17:06',
        '17:27',
        '17:57',
        '20:20',
        '20:45',
        '21:50',
        '23:25',
        '23:30',
        '23:48'
        ];

        $(function() {
            var today = new Date();
            var now = moment([today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getMinutes(), today.getHours(), today.getMinutes()]);

            var setted = '';
            var count = 1;
            for (var i=0; i<train_arrivals.length; i++){
                var entry = train_arrivals[i];

                time = entry.split(":");
                var arrival = moment([today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getMinutes(), time[0], time[1]]);
                diff = arrival.diff(now, 'minutes');

                if (!setted && diff > 0) {
                    $("#arrival_list").append($("<li id="+count+" style='font-size: x-large' class='bg-success'>").text(diff + ' min '));
                    setted = count;
                } else
                $("#arrival_list").append($("<li id="+count+" class='bg-info'>").text(diff + ' min'));

                if (setted && count >= setted + 2) break;

                if (!setted && count > 1)
                    $('#'+count).remove();

                count++;
            }
        });
</script>
```

I have this code for this little web app http://nexttrain.elvismdev.com/

The idea is to show next train arrival to the station due the train arrivals times given at the beginning of the code, the value inside the green row is the first next train approaching to the station, after it are two more train arrivals showing up, and back from it, should show the how many times ago the last train was there. I can't figure it out what is wrong over there that I am getting the wrong value with that so long minutes left, when it should show only a short time period.

If somebody could just look at my code and point me what could I be missing, In real I am not so much proficient in javascript, and time calculations always drive me crazy with issues like this.

Also I am using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding `<ul>` elements to the DOM (Document Object Model) and then deleting them again, why not try this approach: First find the nearest future departure time, and then work backwards and get the time immediately before that. Add the previous time to the DOM as a `<ul>`, and then add the nearest future time. Something like this:

```
    var train_arrivals = [
    '00:10',
    '00:15',
    '00:23',
    '00:35',
    '00:43',
    '00:58',
    '01:05',
    '01:13',
    '01:20',
    '01:37',
    '01:48',
    '02:15',
    '02:25',
    '02:40',
    '02:55',
    '03:00',
    '03:09',
    '03:21',
    '03:37',
    '03:52',
    '04:15',
    '04:30',
    '04:44',
    '04:58',
    '05:16',
    '05:31',
    '05:49',
    '06:00',
    '06:26',
    '06:56',
    '08:06',
    '07:24',
    '07:43',
    '07:58',
    '08:06',
    '08:13',
    '08:28',
    '08:43',
    '08:58',
    '09:05',
    '09:13',
    '09:28',
    '09:43',
    '09:58',
    '10:05',
    '10:38',
    '11:00',
    '11:38',
    '12:38',
    '13:38',
    '14:38',
    '15:38',
    '16:00',
    '16:39',
    '17:00',
    '17:06',
    '17:27',
    '17:57',
    '20:20',
    '20:45',
    '21:50',
    '23:25',
    '23:30',
    '23:48'
    ];

    $(function() {
        var today = moment();
        var todayString = today.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        var now = today;

        var setted = '';
        var count = 1;
        for (var i=0; i<train_arrivals.length; i++){
            var entry = train_arrivals[i];           
            var arrival = moment(todayString + ' ' + entry);
            diff = arrival.diff(now, 'minutes');

            if (!setted && diff > 0) {
                if (i > 0) {
                    var prevEntry = train_arrivals[i - 1];
                    var prevArrival = moment(todayString + ' ' + prevEntry);
                    var prevDiff = prevArrival.diff(now, 'minutes');
                    $("#arrival_list").append($("<li id="+count+" class='bg-info'>").text(prevDiff + ' min'));
                }
                $("#arrival_list").append($("<li id="+count+" style='font-size: x-large' class='bg-success'>").text(diff + ' min '));
                setted = count;
            }
            else if (diff > 0){
            $("#arrival_list").append($("<li id="+count+" class='bg-info'>").text(diff + ' min'));
            }

            if (setted && count >= setted + 2) break;
            count++;
        }
    });
```

Here's a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W84Gm/1/